# Oracle SQL count of unique IDs in moving time window

Tags: sql, time, transactions, oracle-sqldeveloper, distinct-values

I need to query data on a large transaction dataset in a Oracle SQL Developer database but unfortunately I didn't came up with the correct solution yet - hopefully someone can help me.

The dataset consists of the following:
Customer_ID,  Counterparty_ID, Transaction ID, Transaction_Amount, Date

Task :
Flag the transactions of a customer, when a customers made transactions (>= 1000 € each) with >= 5 different counterparties in a 7day time window.

The time window should be a moving time window: E.g. if the transaction date is 17.6. the time window would be +- 6 days (11. - 23.06.).
Within a time window only distinct counterparties should be counted. E.g. if a customer has made 5 transactions with counterparty X in time window A, it is counted as 1. If the customer made additional transactions with counterparty X but in time window B,  it is again counted as 1 for that time window.

So far I was only able to solve the task with calendar weeks as time window but that is not as intended.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; and the expected answer for that sample data and, if it is not obvious, an explanation of how that expected answer was generated. Talking about an abstract problem is fine but its much easier to work with a concrete example.

Comment: If a customer makes five 200€ transactions with the same counterparty within the time window (so the total is 1000€ for that counterparty) does that count or does it have to be a single 1000€ transaction?

Comment: It has to be a single transaction of >= 1000 €

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any sample data or expected output so its difficult to know exactly what you want to output; however, you can immediately filter out all the rows with `transaction_amount < 1000` and then, from Oracle 12, you use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT m.*,
         COUNT(DISTINCT counterparty_id) OVER (
           PARTITION BY customer_id, match
         ) AS num_counterparties
  FROM   (
    SELECT *
    FROM   table_name
    WHERE  transaction_amount >= 1000
  )
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    PARTITION BY customer_id
    ORDER BY "DATE"
    MEASURES
      MATCH_NUMBER() AS match
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
    AFTER MATCH SKIP TO NEXT ROW
    PATTERN ( within_week+ )
    DEFINE
      within_week AS "DATE" < FIRST("DATE") + INTERVAL '7' DAY
  ) m
)
WHERE  num_counterparties >= 5;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  Customer_ID, Counterparty_ID, Transaction_ID, Transaction_Amount, "DATE"
) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1000, DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 2, 1000, DATE '1970-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 3, 1000, DATE '1970-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 4, 4, 1000, DATE '1970-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 5, 5, 1000, DATE '1970-01-05' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CUSTOMER_ID | DATE | MATCH | COUNTERPARTY_ID | TRANSACTION_ID | TRANSACTION_AMOUNT | NUM_COUNTERPARTIES |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 01-JAN-70 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1000 | 5 |
> | 1 | 02-JAN-70 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1000 | 5 |
> | 1 | 03-JAN-70 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 1000 | 5 |
> | 1 | 04-JAN-70 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 1000 | 5 |
> | 1 | 05-JAN-70 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 1000 | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=335dad0c25e18670e6f958ec4b612e42)*